# Найти элемент на странице по атрибуту

Tags: javascript

Есть `<script language="name">` И нужно без использования jquery получить значение этого тега. (тегов script при этом много,но с этим атрибутом только один)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример:

```js
var hello = document.querySelector('script[language="name"]').innerHTML;
console.log(hello);
```

```html
<script language="name"> 
привет
</script>
```

> UPD

Для получения все тегов вам необходимо пройтись по ним циклом:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script[language="name"]');
  for (var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
     console.log(scripts[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: undefined выводит

Comment: А,нет,все,спасибо большое

Comment: А как делать,если таких тегов с атрибутом больше 1?

Comment: @IvanZ добавил в ответ

Comment: Во втором примере забыл `All`, `document.querySelector` - возвращает только один элемент

Comment: @Grundy. да, спасибо, и как я упустил ))